# Spline intersection with a plane in python scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a bunch of 3D data points and I am fitting a surface through them using scipy thin plate splines as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate

# x, y, z are the 3D point coordinates

spline = sp.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='thin_plate', smooth=5, episilon=5)
x_grid = np.linspace(0, 512, 1024)
y_grid = np.linspace(0, 512, 1024)
B1, B2 = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid, indexing='xy')
Z = spline(B1, B2)
```

This fits the surface as desired as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Now what I want to do is be able to query where this spline intersects a given plane.

So, given this fitted surface, how can I query at what `(x, y)` points this surface cuts the plane `(z = 25)` for example.

So, the code above is fitting:

```
z = f(x, y)
```

and now that the `f` is fitted, I wonder if it is possible to do the inverse look up i.e. I want to do `f^{-1}(z)`

Comment: A contour plot (with `levels=[25]` if you only want one contour) is meant for such purpose.   See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342018/how-do-i-plot-3-contours-in-3d-in-matplotlib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445424/surface-and-3d-contour-in-matplotlib) post.

Comment: Could you please include a minimum working and executable example? F.i. including `f` and `x`, `y`, `z` etc... The solution to the question might be really easy. But I need some sample data for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 3D contour plot will nicely interpolate the contour at the desired height:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate

N = 10
x = np.random.uniform(100, 400, N)
y = np.random.uniform(100, 400, N)
z = np.random.uniform(0, 100, N)
# x, y, z are the 3D point coordinates
spline = sp.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='thin_plate', smooth=5, episilon=5)
x_grid = np.linspace(0, 512, 1024)
y_grid = np.linspace(0, 512, 1024)
B1, B2 = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid, indexing='xy')
Z = spline(B1, B2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.contour(B1, B2, Z, levels=[25], offset=25, colors=['red'])
ax.plot_surface(B1, B2, Z, cmap='autumn_r', lw=1, rstride=10, cstride=10, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image: contour]

PS: If you need the xy coordinates of the curve(s), they are stored inside the contour as a list of lists of 2d coordinates

```
contour = ax.contour(B1, B2, Z, levels=[25], offset=25, colors=['red'])
for segments in contour.allsegs:
    for segment in segments:
        print("X:", segment[:,0])
        print("Y:", segment[:,1])
```

Comment: This is a great application of the `offset` parameter for contours! I definetely need to keep this in mind. :)

Comment: There can be multiple disconnected curves on a certain height, and also they aren't necessarily closed in the restricted domain of the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is enough for your end goal, but one one could be to use [numpy.isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) function:

```py
import numpy as np

z_target = 25
msk = np.isclose(Z, z_target)

x_target = B1[msk]
y_target = B2[msk]
```

Notice that you can adjust the tollerance level as you please in `np.isclose`.

Then you can expect that `Z_target = spline(x_target, y_target)` is tollerance away from `z_target`.